# Problem installing markdown preview plugin for gedit on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, gedit

I'm trying to install a [markdown preview plugin](http://www.jpfleury.net/en/software/gedit-markdown.php) for gedit, but when I try to active it, the entry greys out.

Running gedit via the terminal, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<userid>/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/markdown-preview/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from gpdefs import *
ImportError: No module named gpdefs

** (gedit:2107): WARNING **: Error loading plugin 'Markdown Preview'
```

Trying to find **gpdefs**, I only found [one potentially related page](http://my.opera.com/area42/blog/gedit-language-reference-plugin), which suggest I needed gedit-plugins installed, which I did but this didn't seem to have any effect (other than assorted new plugins).

Any suggestions?

Comment: `gpdefs.py` should be in the `PYTHONPATH` at that point but manifestly isn't. I don't know whose job it is to make it so.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of gedit-markdown. Your problem should be fixed in the current version (3.2.1).

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else still experiencing this problem, I managed to get the plugin to activate with a custom script to start up `gedit` that adds the required dir to `PYTHONPATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins
gedit $1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bug. I tried installing it on Ubuntu 10.10 and, even after installing `gedit-plugins`, I saw exactly the same error message. This ML entry[1] suggests that the install script is not configuring the plugin correctly:

> gpdefs (which stands for gedit-plugins definitions) is a file generated by configure, which basically plays the same role as config.h but for 
> python.

If you install `gedit-plugins` then `gpdefs.py` is installed to `/usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins/` but, as Gilles notes, the markdown plugin does not add it to the python path.

[1] http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.apps.epiphany/8711